# How to add ProcessModel to an asp.net core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the following message sporadically in production and test environments

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL,
>   inst: 12, queue: 5, qu: 0, qs: 5, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 38, ar: 0,
>   clientName: , serverEndpoint: Unspecified/redis:6379, keyHashSlot:
>   9800 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side
>   issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)    at
>   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in
>   c:\code\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line
>   2120

It says to check [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

I find that i should add `<processModel autoConfig="false" minIoThreads="250" />`   to  machine.config but i don't have a  machine.config I have a web.config.

I have searched around and everything i have found about processModel  is relating to .net classic not .net core.

How do you set up processModel in .net core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting `System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads` with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()`. More details on this settings [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md). You can also set it through [runtimeconfig.json](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md) file.

Comment: Any idea what the second number should be? ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(250, 250);

Comment: @DaImTo, keep second parameter like this sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netcore-2.0#examples